# Relacionamento entre tabelas

Tags: banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados, mysql

Tenho determinada tabela já criada e populada:

```
CREATE TABLE `formulario` (
  `id` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` varbinary(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `carteira` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `tipo_ocorrencia` varchar(13) NOT NULL,
  `contato` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tel` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mensagem` text NOT NULL,
  `data` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `hora` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3744 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Estou criando esta tabela agora:

```
CREATE TABLE `preformulario` ( 
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`r1` VARCHAR( 3 ) NOT NULL ,
`r2` VARCHAR( 160 ) NOT NULL ,
`r3` VARCHAR( 160 ) NOT NULL ,
`r4` VARCHAR( 160 ) NOT NULL ) ENGINE = MYISAM;
```

Preciso exportar uma tabela que concilie as duas tabelas acima!
O usuário irá informar os dados da tabela `preformulario` e então começará a informar os dados da tabela `formulario`. 
Conforme expliquei, a tabela `formulario` já está populada... Sua ID está no 3744.
Tenho pouca... Quase nada, experiência com MySQL. Preciso saber se preciso criar uma terceira tabela conciliando as duas que citei ou se existe uma solução no meu PHP que já concilia estes dados?

Answer (score 0):

voce não precisa de uma terceira table , criei um view ou uma proc ou mesmo um select que liste os dados que voce deseja mostrar para o usuário 
no insert pege o id da tabela formulário e insira na outra tabela. Isso é um relacionamento de muitos para muitos

Comment: Olá, @Regis Faria. Não entendi muito bem, meu caro! O que quis dizer com "insert pege"?
Da forma como explicou eu consigo vincular o mesmo usuário? Tipo, se o cara preencher a primeira tabela e preencher a segunda, como faço pra vincular as duas inserções... Exibir as duas em um único SELECT?

Answer (score 0):

list dados das duas tabelas relacionadas atráves de um select, view ou procudure isso para exibir para o usuario. Nesse select voce trará o id da tabela `formulario` que é o que voce precisa para fazer o insert na tabela preformulario`
Geralmente é assim que se faz.

Comment: Não é isso.. Não esclareci a dúvida. Não dependo tabela `formulário` para fazer insert na `preformulario`. Eu só preciso conciliar o que foi inserido na `preformulario` ao que for inserido na `formulário`. O mesmo usuário irá inserir dados nas duas.